# Using result of test-path to execute powershell command

Tags: powershell

Looking to execute a powershell command that will uninstall an application and clear some registry entries if either a file/folder is not present on the system.

Currently looking at something like this:

```
if(!(test-path “c:\Windows\mdm” )
    {
    $productdetails=(Get-WmiObject -Query “Select IdentifyingNumber from win32_product where name = ‘Tesapp’“).identifyingnumber
    $proc=(Start-Process -FilePath “msiexec.exe” -ArgumentList “/x $productdetails /qn /l*v c:\temp\Uninstall-testapp.log” -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode
if (!($proc -eq 0 -or $proc -eq 3010))
 {
    exit(1)
    }
$RegKey=“HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TestAppManagement\S-0-0-00-0000000000-0000000000-000000000-000\MSI\{0}” -f $productdetails
if(test-path $RegKey)
    {
   $op= Get-Item $RegKey | Out-File “c:\windows\temp\TestApp_Reg_backup.reg” -Force
   $op= Remove-Item $RegKey -Force
    }
    }
```

Interestingly if I run the test path it will return false which is expected, or if run the app uninstall/reg clear on its own it will work as intended - however i cannot run them together.

I assume i am making some sort of syntax/ basic logic error?

Comment: When the path is not present, you run an uninstall. Then you expect to find registry keys to remove after that uninstall happens? Is your `exit` statement closing the script early here?

Comment: `$RegKey` is using smart curly quotes (`“”`) rather than dumb straight quotes (`""`) this causes errors in many different coding languages, fortunately powershell is smarter than that, however, as a habit you should still use straight quotes.

Comment: Correct - the uninstall does not remove the reg entries. The uninstall has to be done prior to the reg entries being removed.

Comment: @AdminOfThings You are correct - looks to be the exit closing too early - if I remove this or move it below the value for $RegKey then the command completes